# exporting a query output to a text file

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

I have an access query which I am trying to export to a text file using the following code:

```
DoCmd.TransferText acExportFixed, "Export Specification", _
    "Test Query", "C:\Users\Documents\TestOutput.txt", True
```

The issue I am having is: The output file "TestOutput.txt" has the data displayed with fixed width but the column headers are comma delimited. I want the column headers to be fixed width too.

What would column headers not be displayed same as the rest of the data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAICT, that is an unavoidable "feature" of TransferText.  It seems to lack any kind of built-in intelligence to say "OK, we're exporting as acExportFixed, so let's examine the column widths defined in Export Specification and output the column headers using those same widths".  Instead it just gives the column names as a comma-separated list.

As with everything else in Access, when its default behaviors are unsatisfactory, you can write VBA code to do it your way.

```
Const VB_FORREADING = 1
Const VB_FORWRITING = 2
Const cstrFile As String = "C:\Users\Documents\TestOutput.txt"
Const cstrHeaderRow As String = "col1    col2    etc..."
Dim oFSO As Object
Dim oFile As Object
Dim strContents As String

' do TransferText without the field names '
' (HasFieldNames default = False) '
DoCmd.TransferText acExportFixed, "Export Specification", _
    "Test Query", cstrFile 

Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
' read file content into strContents string variable '
Set oFile = oFSO.OpenTextFile(cstrFile, VB_FORREADING)
strContents = oFile.ReadAll
oFile.Close
' re-write file using cstrHeaderRow plus strContents '
Set oFile = oFSO.OpenTextFile(cstrFile, VB_FORWRITING)
oFile.write cstrHeaderRow & vbCrLf & strContents
oFile.Close

Set oFile = Nothing
Set oFSO = Nothing
```

Comment: Instead of creating a text file using DoCmd.TransferText and then editing it with FileSystemObject, I may have to write the query output directly to a text file. Is this possible?

Comment: Sure.  The FileSystemObject's file object includes writeline method which you may prefer over the write method for that purpose.  It can certainly be done, but my gut reaction is it could require a lot more code than what I suggested.  Go for it!

Comment: What steps would I need to follow? Would I need to open a recordset and then loop through the ouput and write each line?

Comment: my apologies, I was looking to write a file from access query ouput, didnt know DoCmd.TransferText needs an existing file to write to it and I just found out that I dont need column headers in the output file.