# writing a query output to text file using FileSystemObject

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007, filesystemobject

Is there a way to write a query output to a text file using FileSystemObject?

Comment: This is not a sensible question, and you are not interacting with the people who have answered your questions, for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9449654/exporting-a-query-output-to-a-text-file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's the format of the query results? you may be able to do something like this if it's a simple string, or you may have to extract the bits that you need.

Here's the code to write a string to a text file using the filesystemobject:

```
Const fsoForAppend = 8

Dim objFSO
Dim queryResult

queryResult = 'OMG no results'

Set objFSO = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'Open the text file
Dim objTextStream
Set objTextStream = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\path\to\logfile.txt", fsoForAppend)

'Write the results to the textfile
objTextStream.WriteLine queryResult

'Close the file and clean up
objTextStream.Close
Set objTextStream = Nothing
Set objFSO = Nothing
```

Comment: the query outputs data from a table, so its in table format. Also, I dont have an existing file to open and append, I'll have to create a new file and write the query output to it.

Comment: If the file doesn't exist, opening it in fsoForAppend mode should create it for you.

As for your query result, it's probably going to be a recordset so the best approach may be to loop over it and output a row at a time.