# Access VBA invalid procedure call or argument

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007, filesystemobject

I am trying to write a query output to a text file using file system object.

Here is my code so far:

```
Sub CreateAfile()

Dim rs As Object

Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
Dim objFile As Object, TextFile As Object
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("qryOutput")

Set objFile = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set TextFile = objFile.CreateTextFile("C:\Users\Documents\Test.txt", True)

rs.MoveFirst
Do Until rs.EOF

TextFile.WriteLine rs.Fields("field1").Value

rs.MoveNext
Loop
rs.Close
TextFile.Close

End Sub
```

I get an error: "Invalid procedure call or argument"
At line: TextFile.WriteLine rs.Fields("field1").Value

Am i missing something here?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9468488/writing-a-query-output-to-text-file-using-filesystemobject

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have that folder, *C:\Users\Documents*, on my system.  So your code gives me error #76, "Path not found", on the `CreateTextFile` line.  Changing the folder to one which exists, and where I have full permission, allows the code to run without error.  I don't understand why you're getting an error at  `TextFile.WriteLine`.

These two lines seem contradictory.

```
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("qryOutput")
```

`CurrentDb.OpenRecordset` returns a DAO recordset rather than an ADO recordset.  However, since rs was declared as an object, VBA doesn't care that you first assigned an ADO recordset to it before you re-assign a DAO recordset to it.  I don't see how this contributes to your error, but I would discard the `CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")` line anyway.  Also, change the declaration for rs to:

```
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
```

(You will need to set a reference if the compiler complains about that declaration.)

Aside from that, I still don't understand why you're getting an "Invalid procedure call or argument" error.

Comment: Filesystemobject and user793468 : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9468488/writing-a-query-output-to-text-file-using-filesystemobject
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9470232/invalid-procedure-call-or-agrument 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9442215/reading-and-writing-a-csv-file-using-filesystemobject/9442846#9442846

Comment: The other 2 questions each consisted of a single sentence.  In this one, the OP showed us code, described an error, and identified the line  which triggered it.  I want to encourage this type of question.  So I attempted an answer.